# Get an error message "Cannot save the customer." when a new user signs up

Tags: magento-1.9

Once user register, they get an error message "Cannot save the customer.". The account actually is made.

I have tried this code and error shows "Cannot save the customer.**Decoding failed: Syntax error**"

```
catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            //$session->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.' . $e->getMessage()));
        }
```

[image]

Comment: did you checked logs in var/logs ? 
over there you will get exact problem.

Comment: @Magento2 Learner yes I have checked logs but i did not get any error log

Comment: You can check the trace of the exception with `exception->getTraceAsString()`, it will help you to go back to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a php7 issue. If so... try **Inchoo**'s Magento PHP 7 compatibility module https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7